# PHP mail - headers doesnt work with variables

Tags: php, email, variables, header

Heres my little code

```
$to = 'target@adress.pl';
$adres='author@adress.pl';
define('ADR','author@adress.pl');

$subject='Invoice delivery confirmation for '.$adres;
$message=$adres.' confirmed invoice delivery';

$headers = "From: ".$adres."\r\n" .
"Reply-To: ".$adres."\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" ;

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) echo ' Confirmation has been sent to '.$to.'<br />';`
```

When i use variables with or without concatenation then headers in sending message are empty - they are replaced with default admin adress. Offcourse variable $adress itself is not empty as it works properly in $subject and $message variables. But if i replace variables with ADR constant or plain text then they do work. Is it PHP, server settings or something else?

Comment: You have a lot of typo's in `$adres` (also $address), please post the actual code.

Comment: Ok i corrected mistakes.